# Not sure why I'm getting this error, "System.QueryException: unexpected token: "

Tags: apex, unit-test

Not sure why I'm getting this error, "System.QueryException: unexpected token:

```
 public class InputLookupComponentControllerTest{
     testMethod public static void testGetRecords(){

         List<String> userL = new List<String>();
         userL.add(UserInfo.getName());
         String searchV = UserInfo.getName();
         InputLookupComponentController.getRecords(userL, searchV);

    }
}
```

// This is the InputLookupComponentController Class

```
public with sharing class InputLookupComponentController {

    /**
     * The maximum number of records returned from the query.
     * This is limited to prevent long round trip times from sending too much data
     * back to the client.
     */
    private static final Integer MAX_RECORDS = 10;

    /** This is a lightning component controller. It should never be instantiated. */
    private InputLookupComponentController() {

    }

    /**
     * Does a sosl search against the types of objects given with the search val
     * Defaults to search Name fields and returning Id, Name for each type
     * Limits to 10 return records for better UX.
     * 
     * @param types Array of API strings
     * @param searchVal the value we are searching for
     * @return list of records who name fields match our search
     */
    @AuraEnabled
    public static SObject[] getRecords(final String[] types, final String searchVal) {
        if (types.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException('sobjectType cannot be null or white space.');
        } else if (String.isBlank(searchVal)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException('searchField cannot be null or white space.');
        }

        String sosl = 'FIND \'*' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchVal) + '*\'' + ' IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING ';
        for (Integer i = 0, n = types.size(); i < n; i++) {
            final String s = String.escapeSingleQuotes(types[i]);
            sosl += s + '(Id, Name)';
            if (n > 1 && i != n - 1) { sosl += ','; }
            sosl += ' ';
        }
        sosl += 'LIMIT ' + MAX_RECORDS;

        List<SObject> ret = new List<SObject>();
        for (List<SObject> lst : Search.query(sosl)) {
            ret.addAll(lst);
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: share the code for `InputLookupComponentController.getRecords(userL, searchV);` method. This code don't have any issue.

Comment: @TusharSharma I add the code on the bottom of the original post.

Comment: try to debug the SOSl query and see what you get.

Comment: Try printing the sosl variable you might be getting an extra ","

Answer (score 0):

You may have problem in " searchVal " variable. Try to debug the " searchVal " and " Types " in your code. I have executed the below code and it's not throwing error.

```
List<String> types = new List<String>{'Lead','Contact'};
String sosl = 'FIND \'*' + String.escapeSingleQuotes('Alex') + '*\'' + ' IN 
NAME FIELDS RETURNING ';
for (Integer i = 0, n = types.size(); i < n; i++) {
        final String s = String.escapeSingleQuotes(types[i]);
        sosl += s + '(Id, Name)';
        if (n > 1 && i != n - 1)
        { 
            sosl += ','; 
        }
        sosl += ' ';
    }
sosl += 'LIMIT 10';
System.debug('&& sosl ----->'+sosl);
Search.query(sosl);
```